# Is it is possible to boot an android via cmd if debug is not enabled?

Tags: android

So my problem is as follows: I want to boot up my android via adb since its power button is broken and it was left uncharged for a while. The reason is that there are few apps on it that I would like to quickly do some minor stuff with and that's about it (if it is impossible then no biggie).

Is it then possible to enable the usb debugging via adb and then execute the restart command?

Comment: You can't enable USB debugging if its not already on.  ANd if its off, you can't restart it-  nothing is listening over USB.

Comment: True, fair point. Oh well, useless phone it is.

Comment: SInce its a brick anyway-  you might be able to open it up and close the circuit the power button usually does by hand with a wire.  Or there may be a pressure pad you can push directly.

Comment: Could try that, never have before nor would I really know where to begin with opening this one plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but what you can do is plug the USB cable connected to your computer while holding down the Volume Down button on your device.

That gets you to recovery mode. So you should be able to type `fastboot devices` and get back a result of your device connected. If that works, all you need to do is type `fastboot reboot` and the device will reboot.